# How to handle expensive data stored on .data property of jQuery not to get lost on PostBack?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, browser-cache, stateless

I have some expensive data which I preferred to store as a JavaScript object.

Basically I generate a JavaScript that declares an array and it finds a `<table>` element on page and stores this data on table element by using the jQuery .data property. An I register this java script as a startup script.

It works perfectly fine but on the post-back I am loosing it not surprisingly.

Can you suggest me a convenient way to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

html 5 web storage, http://www.puremango.co.uk/2010/05/caching-in-javascript-with-cachejs/

Comment: A little warning : doesn't work for every browser. Guess which one obviously won't allow you to do that ;)

Comment: It's been supported since IE8 if that's what you're thinking off :)

Comment: Exactly. more and more project drop IE 6 support, but I not so many allow to drop IE 7 support.